# Create a block storage endurance through the API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have deployed a block storage endurance by placing an order through the API, and I am wondering how can I get the id and the name of the created bock storage.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the identifier (id) and username from your Block Storage - Endurance, using the **orderId** that [SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder) method returns.

You can use the following REST request for it:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"id":{"operation":6359215}}}}}}
```

Method: Get

Note: Replace $user, $apiKey with your own information. Replace 6359215 value with your **orderId** value.