# How can we capture storage_Id while placing order for storage (either performance or endurance)?

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am placing order for a block storage and I need to capture storage Id  generated for that storage as soon as we places order. Please help  me in capturing the storage id. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is duplicated see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038042/create-a-block-storage-endurance-through-the-api

Answer (score 0):

After placing an order, the response has a property can help us to find the `storageId`, this is the `”orderId”`. Please try the following Rest request using filters:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectFilter={"networkStorage":{"billingItem":{"orderItem":{"order":{"id":{"operation":5208963}}}}}}

Method: GET

Where `”5208963”` is the `”orderId”` (Please change it).
```